# Can we play alarm ringtone using EventKit?

Tags: ios, objective-c, eventkit, alarms

After searching a lot, I did not get any idea to play alarm tone/music when an event fires. By using EventKit I can only get a alert when the event is fired but there is no alarm music. So Can anybody let me know is it possible to play music/alarm tone using EventKit, If Yes, Then please guide me how to achieve this.

Below code only displays the alert at the time of event

```
    if (self.eventStore == nil) {
    self.eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
}

[self.eventStore requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
    if (granted) {
        NSLog(@"Aceess to calendar");


        EKEvent *event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:self.eventStore];
        event.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
        event.title = @"Good Morning";
        event.startDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:60];
        event.endDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:600];

        EKAlarm *alarm = [EKAlarm alarmWithRelativeOffset:60];
        [event addAlarm:alarm];

        [event setCalendar:[eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];

        NSError *err;
        [eventStore saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&err];
        // Add event to iPhone Calendar

    }else
        NSLog(@"Access to calaendar denied");
}];
```

Thank you

Comment: Refer below link for setting tone using settings app..!
http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/79816/how-can-i-have-calendar-use-an-audible-alarm-for-alerts